# IIS7 & IE8 - Pages rendering differently on same versions of IE8?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, internet-explorer-8

I have an ASP.NET (framework 2.0) web app running under IIS7.
When I run the app on the server, using IE8, localhost the app runs the way it is supposed to.
When I run the app in Visual Studio 2008 (framework 2.0) it runs the way it is supposed to.
But when I try to run the app from another computer it renders incorrectly.
Same versions of IE8.

What would cause the serving of an ASP.NET application to render correctly on the server, but incorrectly when serving to another computer, when the Internet Explorer versions are the same?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have compatability mode switched on on one of the computers? There is a little torn page icon next to the address bar, if it is clicked then it renders the page differently.

Comment: Compatibility mode of IE perhaps?

Comment: Looks like this : https://www.goarmyed.com/images/browserSettings/IE8/compatability_mode.jpg

Comment: Use fiddler (HTTP Proxy) to compare headers on both request. You can also run SMSNIFF on the server to look at the traffic for both. 
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html
smsniff needs admin permission to run but it doesn't need to be installed.

Comment: SLC, no the page appears to be compatible.  Not 'incompatibility' icon shown.

Comment: Okay, just noticed something...
On the server, IE8 (localhost) has the compatibility icon showing.
when I click the torn page, the rendered page looks incorrect.
Does that mean that the page that looks good is incompatible?

Comment: Is there a setting in IIS7 to serve page with compatibility mode turned off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force IE to work in a specific compatability mode with one of the following meta tags in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=4">   <!-- IE5 mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7.5" > <!-- IE7 mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=100" > <!-- IE8 mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=a" >   <!-- IE5 mode -->
```

Here is a link to more information regarding the compatibility meta tag:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx

One other thing you could try is to save the output source on each system and then compare to see if they are the same.  If they are identical then it comes down to the rending on the client which is a compatibility setting.

Comment: Another strange thing is that the browser on my desktop (IE8) does not have the 'compatibility mode' button.  When I right click the toolbar, the 'Compatiblility View Button' is checked, however it does not show up.

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by adding an entry into the HTTP Response Headers section of IIS7.  I added:
Name:  X-UA-Compatible
Value:  IE=100
So far, the site seems to be working correctly now.