# Why does 'string'[0] behave differently on ie8 + IIS7.5 than other browsers or local file?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, iis-7.5

Consider the following Html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('' +
                '\'test\'[0] = \'' + 'test'[0] + '\'\n' +
                '\'test\'.charAt(0) = \'' + 'test'.charAt(0) + '\'\n'
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open this file on my local machine it gives the following output (both in ie8 and Chrome):

```
'test'[0] = 't'
'test'.charAt(0) = 't'
```

When I host this file on IIS7.5 I still get the same result in Chrome but ie8 gives the following result:

```
'test'[0] = 'undefined'
'test'.charAt(0) = 't'
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found out it was due to compatibility view. Internet explorer comes standard (I think, I am not the owner of this laptop) with the option to display all intranet pages in compatibility View. To force it to use ie8 compatibility view I had to add the following meta tag to the head element:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" > <!-- IE8 mode -->
```

You can also turn this option off under 'Page' > 'Compatibility View Settings'

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746163/iis7-ie8-pages-rendering-differently-on-same-versions-of-ie8) has put me in the right direction.

**EDIT:** I advise web developers to leave this option checked in ie8, because most of your users will have it checked. This way you will catch these errors in the development cycle.

**EDIT2:** sv_in is right. `IE=edge` is much cleaner.

Comment: putting `content` property as `IE=100` is ok but IMO, `IE=edge` would be much better. This value would choose the latest IE version rendering (though it is done by yours too). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx#SetMode

Comment: Indeed, funny thing is: the page you quote also uses my method somewhere, In this paragraph: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx#Content

Comment: Yours is cleaner so I updated my answer. I suspect the msdn page has been updated since I posted my answer because I think I copied it from that page.

Answer (score 0):

Jan, just to add to your own answer, the more standards compliant way to enable compatibility view would be to just use a standard doctype at the beginning of your document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Which is the HTML5 doctype, should put you into standards mode as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity I tested this answer. It doesn't work. The setting in internet explorer appears to be overriding any doctype information.

Comment: Odd - I've used it myself in the past. Here's an article clarifying: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/


It may be that there's something else about your document that's breaking it from standards mode. Maybe it has to validate?

Comment: no it validates, it's the ie. regardless of the doctype, ie shows every intranet page in compatibility view. Unless you force it with a metatag.