# Why does `mystring[0]` not return anything in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

So in my javascript I have the following code:

```
    var wholeHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    var data = new Object();

    // Remove the bang or slash if one appears at the beginning
    if (wholeHash[0] == '!') { wholeHash = wholeHash.substring(1); }
    if (wholeHash[0] == '/') { wholeHash = wholeHash.substring(1); }
```

When this is about to run, `wholeHash` has a value of `"/search/&&stype=quick"`.  However, `wholeHash[0]` returns nothing, which causes `wholeHash[0] == '!'` to be false.  This is only the case in IE.

Why is this?  I am aware I can instead use `startswith` but I am generally interested why IE cannot get individual characters of a string while the other browsers can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because indexing into strings with array style indexing is new, and older versions of IE lack this. Instead you will need to use `mystring.charAt(0)` if you need to support IE's before 8.

Comment: Pardon me, but IE ***has*** implemented it. Just maybe not in whatever primitive version of IE you're still using.

Comment: I'm using IE9 so no, it doesn't have this

Comment: There seems to be some inconsistencies as to which version of IE has this and which doesn't. Probably has to do with what mode IE is running in (quirks versus standards, and the backwards compatibility modes)

Comment: @KallDrexx Use `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>`, and you'll get it, and much more nice things too.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem a while ago. In my case it had to do with compatibility view being automatically turned on on intranet pages. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3985605/419436).

Answer (score 1):

The "proper" way to get a character from a string is with `mystring.charAt(x)`.

However you can break a string into an array with `mystring.split("")`.

Up to you which you prefer.